# Comparing old (cached) entity with updated entity without angering nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am updating an entity in a form, for simplicity, lets call it CompanyCar. My objective is to check and see if its assigned owner has changed, and if so, send an email to the old and new owner.

```
public Car SaveExistingCar(Car car)
        {


            var original = _CarRepository.LoadCarById(Car.Id);


            var carReturn = _CarRepository.SaveOrUpdateCar(Car)   //Error here


             //pseudo: if carReturn.Owner != original.Owner
             // Send Email


        return carReturn;
    }
```

Unfortunately it gets mighty angry about this.

```
 a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

I can understand whats making that happen... sure, okay its confused about the real object. However, that doesn't do much to help me solve it. Is there something I can do to tell it that the 'original' is bogus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISession.Evict` will remove the original car from the session and 1st level cache and you should be able to save the new car.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Should have tried that before posting. Just finished updating my repository to have an EvictCar method when you posted.